# Eclipse git getting wrong relative path on file

Tags: android, eclipse, git, egit

I am trying to add and commit two files to a github repo using the git extension to eclipse.  I have been using this repo setup without issue for several weeks.

I just tried to add the file set_player_info.xml to the repo, but Egit is getting the wrong relative path to the file (see pictured).

Any ideas on how to rectify this?  I cannot find a similar issue anywhere, nor have I had any luck with a solution.[image: Listed incorrect relative path]

Comment: Could you try if it also happens with an updated EGit from the [nightly update site](http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-nightly)? There was a fix recently which may help here. Otherwise please [report this as a bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=EGit), with as much information as possible.